# PHP loop after third file input not added in array?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I am adding a document's name and image to a database via PHP.
The name is inserted but the uploaded image isn't inserted after the third and not coming loop or array.

Please can anyone tell me if it's the loop or the array or the query that is incorrect.

Here is my code:

```
$stock_no = $_POST["txt_stock_no"]; //hidden input 
$doc_name = $_POST["chk"];
$doc_file = $_FILES["doc_file"]["name"];
$doc_tmp_name = $_FILES["doc_file"]["tmp_name"];
$add_by=charEsc($_SESSION["User_ID"]);

foreach ($doc_name as $value => $b) {
    $image_new = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
    $ext = end(explode(".", $doc_file[$value])); //gets extension

    move_uploaded_file($doc_tmp_name[$value],"assets/documents/" .$image_new."-".$stock_no.".".$ext);

    $rep = query("INSERT INTO documents ( `stock_no`, `Document_Name`, `Document_Upload`)  Values ('$stock_no','$doc_name[$value]','assets/documents/" .$image_new."-".$stock_no.".".$ext."')");
}
```

Comment: Please restate your question. It is not clear what works and what does not work. I can spot at least two things wrong in the code: 1) missing `}` and 2) the `$doc_name` is obtained from `$_POST` and is a string. You cannot use a string in a `foreach` the way you present it here.

Comment: after your edit: is this the complete code? Because the part `foreach ($doc_name as $value => $b)` really should give a PHP Warning and (especially without knowing wat `$doc_name`'s value is) will probably never run the loop. What do you expect the type and value of `$doc_name` to be?

Comment: another thing to check: what is the maximum upload size? This depends not only on the MAX_FILE_SIZE hidden field in the form (I suppose you use this? Your really should), but also on the settings in php.ini and perhaps server settings. Often, this is only 2 MB. What is the total size of the files you upload? Perhaps the loop starts to fail after the maximum size is exceeded? Also check the values in `$_FILES["doc_file"]["error"]`!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one and it is working for me:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['form_submit']))
{
        $stock_no=$_POST["txt_stock_no"]; //hidden input 
        $doc_name = $_POST["chk"];
        $doc_file = $_FILES["doc_file"]["name"];
        $doc_tmp_name = $_FILES["doc_file"]["tmp_name"];
        #$add_by=charEsc($_SESSION["User_ID"]);


        for($i=0; $i<count($stock_no); $i++)
        {
            $image_new= md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
            $ext=explode(".", $doc_file[$i]);//gets extension
            $ext=end($ext);
            move_uploaded_file($doc_tmp_name[$i],"images/".$image_new."-".$stock_no[$i].".".$ext);
            #echo "image path=".$doc_tmp_name[$i]." ///"."images/".$image_new."-".$stock_no[$i].".".$ext."<br>";
            $stock_no=$stock_no[$i];
            $doc_name=$doc_file[$i];
            $document_path="images/".$image_new."-".$stock_no[$i].".".$ext;
            $rep = query("INSERT INTO documents ( `stock_no`, `Document_Name`, `Document_Upload`)  values ('$stock_no','$doc_name','$document_path')"); 
        }
}
?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php 
for($i=0; $i<=3; $i++)
{
    ?>
      <input type="text" name="chk[]" />
      <input type="text" name="txt_stock_no[]" />
      <input type="file" name="doc_file[]" />
      <br />
    <?php
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="form_submit" />
</form>
```